# How to write database integration test properly in Play 2.1?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, integration-testing

I am new at Play! 2.1. I'm trying to TDD my database integration test. After reading the examples on the website. I wrote my test like this.

```
    @Test
    public void shouldGetDealName() {
        running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                List books = Book.find.all();
                Assert.assertEquals(books.size(), 1);
            }
        });
    }
```

My question would be, do I need to wrap the code in `running(fakeAppliation()...` all the time? Because if I run this code without the fakeApplication. It doesn't seem to work. If it has to be like that then is there a better way to do this in Java? It seems wrong for me to wrap the code in that block every time for integration or functional test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, assuming you want to use in-memory DB and you want it to be recreated for each test:

```
public class ApplicationTest extends WithApplication {
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        start(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase(), fakeGlobal()));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetDealName() {
        List books = Book.find.all();
        Assert.assertEquals(books.size(), 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I want to use MySQL instead of inMemoryDatabase? would that change things a lot?

Comment: inMemoryDatabase() will just create a Map with DB settings for you - take a look in the source. You can create right configuration manually and pass it in.